# How to manualy uninstall Magento plugin?

Tags: magento

help me with magento , I am new in , I instaled plugin 
http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/social-login-and-social-share-by-janrain.html

and now site is down

how to manualy uninstall it ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to remove magento extension manually, then follow the steps below:

1. Disable the module from this file
   `/app/etc/modules/<your_module>.xml`
   set `<active>true</active>` to `<active>false</active>`
2. If their is any dependent my sql table, Remove tables.
3. Remove resource config record for the respective module from  `core_recource` table in database.
4. Remove the `<project_root>/var/cache` folder
5. Refresh you home page or any other page.

It should be removed now, I hope this can be  helpful to one.

Comment: you probably meant `var/cache`

Comment: Yes `<project_root>/var/catch` thanks for highlighting.

Comment: you meant `<project_root>/var/cache`? :D

Answer (score 0):

If you want remove all files regarding that extension, you just go to the following link [CLICK ME](http://freegento.com/ddl-magento-extension.php) . Here just add your installed extension key. then now you can download the extension in a zip format. you can see all installed files by extracting this zip file. So you can easily remove all files from your site by following that file path.

Comment: instep of this you can also find in downloader folder > .cache folder whole extension

Answer (score 0):

Use [MEFF](https://github.com/tegansnyder/meff) - Magento Extension File Finder.

Simple clone this repo and run the meff.php file via the command line passing it a extension name and full path to your Magento root directory.

`php meff.php Extension_Name MagentoDir`

Answer (score 0):

Steps to uninstall a composer installed module/extension/plugin

Step 1: Open CMD goto the root folder and type the following cmd to check if the module is enabled or disabled.
php bin/magento module:status

Step 2:  Disable the module by executing below commands:

```
php bin/magento module:disable <ExtensionProvider_ExtensionName> --clear-static-content

php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

Step 3: Remove extension files

```
cd app/code/<ExtensionProvider>/
rm -force <ExtensionName>
```

Step 4: Remove the record with module <ExtensionProvider_ExtensionName> from the table setup_module

Step 5: Remove the line with <ExtensionProvider_ExtensionName> from app/etc/config.php
and in all files in composer folder specially from autoload* files.

Steps to uninstall a manually added module/extension/plugin in app/code

1. bin/magento module:disable Namespace_ModuleName
2. remove directory from app/code manually
3. bin/magento setup:upgrade
4. bin/magento cache:flush